# Show $E[XY|G]=E[X|G]\cdot E[Y|G]$ whenever $X,Y \in L^2$ are independent.

Tags: proof-verification, conditional-expectation

> Let $X,Y \in L^2$ be independent random variables and $G$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra. Then
>   $$E[XY|G]=E[X|G]\cdot E[Y|G].$$

Here is my alleged proof: Since $X,Y \in L^2$, all the conditional expectations are well-defined. Then
$$
\begin{align}E[XY|G]&=E\bigg[E[XY|\sigma(G,X)]\big|G\bigg]\ \ \ \  (\because\text{tower property})
\\&=E\bigg[X\ E[Y|\sigma(G,X)]\big|G\bigg]
\\&=E\bigg[X\ E[Y|G]\big|G\bigg] \ \ \ \ (\because \text{$X$ and $Y$ indep})
\\&=E[Y|G]\cdot E[X|G]  \ \ \ (\because \text{$E[Y|G]$ is $G$ measurable})
\end{align}$$ 
yields the result.

Is my proof okay? Any help is appreciated.

---

As I commented, there is a gap in the second to the last step; we need that $X$ is independent with $\sigma(Y,G)$.

Comment: @MarsPlastic I think I made a mistake in that step.  Independence of  $X$ and $\sigma(G,Y)$ is required, not just $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ be two independent identically distributed random variables taking the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $X=\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2$, $Y=\varepsilon_1$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma(\varepsilon_2)$. Then $X$ is independent of $Y$, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[XY\mid \mathcal G\right]=\mathbb E\left[ \varepsilon_2\mid \mathcal G\right]=\varepsilon_2
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb E\left[Y\mid \mathcal G\right]=0.
$$
Therefore, it seems that we cannot avoid the independence of $X$ with $\sigma(\mathcal G,Y)$ or a similar assumption by interchanging $X$ and $Y$.